# validate array of promises one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

I have a function that creates me and array of promises. I can satisfy that whole array by using something like

```
Promise.all(array).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [true, true, true] 
});
```

But what I'm trying to do is validate each item of the array and then using chai expect each value to be true. I can use something like Promise.resolve to specify an index in the array and perform my validation on a particular one.

So ideally I would like to take the array of values and loop through the array performing a test on each value until the array is done, and then once it is done implement a callback (as I'm using protractor with cucumber)

Off the top of my head I thought something like the following would work, but all I get back is array.then is not a function, although when I promise all on the array I can see the values.

```
array.then((values) => {
    let count = 0;
    values.forEach((check) => {
        chai.expect(check).to.be.true();
    });
    count += 1;
    count >= values.length ? callback() : null;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `Promise.all` on the array of derived promises which give the same value as the original promises, but will have applied the chai test to their results:

```
Promise.all(array.map(prom => 
    prom.then( value => (chai.expect(value).to.be.true, value) )
)).then(values => { 
    console.log(values); // [true, true, true] 
    callback();
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('failure', err);
});
```

Comment: This returns some unhandled promises and hang's going through it seems.

Comment: What do you mean with *unhandled promises*?

Comment: my mistake, I had to take the () off the to.be.true. It is running for both positive and negative tests now which is great, but could you explain what the , value part is doing?

Comment: The `value` is used as final argument of the comma operator to make sure the promise returned by `then` is that value en not `to.be.true`.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all will resolve the array of promises into an array of values. Then you just have to iterate over those values with your assertion.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(true);
var promise2 = Promise.resolve(true);
var arrayOfPromises = [promise1, promise2]
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(arrayOfValues=> { 
    console.log(arrayOfValues); // [true, true]
    arrayOfValues.forEach((value) => {
        chai.expect(value).to.be.true;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Although this example doesn't handle rejections in the array with callbacks. then callback after it has been done